# Derivation of probability distribution - Drawing from an urn

Tags: probability

Hello I'm trying to understand a solution to a stochastic problem:

> An urn contains a black and a white ball. A ball is drawn and replaced. Each time a white is drawn another black ball will be put in the urn. Let $X$ be the first time a black ball is drawn.
>   Then $$P(X=k)=k/(k+1)!$$

First they calculate $$P(X>k)=\left[2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots\cdot(k+1)\right]^{-1}$$ 
(First the probability is $1/2$ for getting a black ball, in the next draw it will be $1/3$ and so on.)

The result then follows by:
$$P(X=k)=P(X>k-1)-P(X>k)=1/k!-1/(k+1)!=k/(k+1)!$$

I don't understand the first equality. I have some notion that it could come from the complementary event:

\begin{align}P(X=k)&=1-P(X \neq k)=1-P(X<k \wedge X\geq k-1)\\&=1-[P(X<k)+P(X\geq k-1)]\\&=1-P(X<k)-P(X\geq k-1)\\&=P(X\geq k-1)-P(X\geq k)\end{align}

It would be nice if someone could correct me and\or explain how it is done.
Sorry for the long post for such a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast response. I think I understood the first part now, what I don't understand is how exactly they use $P(X>k)$ to get $P(X=k)$.

I tried deriving it but I don't seem to get the correct answer. (I get $\geq$ instead of $>$).

I think I'm messing something up regarding the complement event? Or have they made a mistake?

Here's my calculation:

> \begin{align}P(X=k)&=1-P(X \neq k)=1-P(X<k \wedge X\geq k-1)\\&=1-[P(X<k)+P(X\geq k-1)]\\&=1-P(X<k)-P(X\geq k-1)\\&=P(X\geq k-1)-P(X\geq k)\end{align}

I'm still new to this forum. Can I do some command to make the last calculation "click to show" instead of this spoiler thing?